# Getting Error on Fragment Transaction(Null Object Reference)

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-mvp

I am new to **Android Development** and I am getting some errors on my code.I am trying to set the Fragment(dashboard,expense,income) that i want for my HomeActivity through the setFragment function.But i want to implement an MVP approach so I created the Presenter class and the Contract interface.My problem is that i cannot implement this function through the presenter and i dont know why.I tried to get the Context,to get Activity,also to play with fragment manager but it doesnt work and it throws Null pointer Exception.

## HomeActivityContract

```
package georgiosApp.manager;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;

public interface HomeActivityContract
{
interface View {
     void setFragment(Fragment fragment);
}
interface Presenter{
     void setFragment1(Fragment fragment);
       }
}
```

## HomeActivity

```
package georgiosApp.manager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView;

import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

import georgiosApp.manager.Fragments.DashBoardFragment;
import georgiosApp.manager.Fragments.ExpenseFragment;
import georgiosApp.manager.Fragments.IncomeFragment;
 import georgiosApp.manager.MainActivityMVP.MainActivity;

public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener,HomeActivityContract.View{

    private BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;
    private FrameLayout frameLayout;
    public HomeActivityPresenter presenter;

    //Fragment

    private DashBoardFragment dashBoardFragment;
    private IncomeFragment incomeFragment;
    private ExpenseFragment expenseFragment;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

       InitViews();
        bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) 
            {
                 switch (item.getItemId()){

                case R.id.dashboard:
                    setFragment(dashBoardFragment);

 bottomNavigationView.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colordas);
                    return true;

                case R.id.income:
                    setFragment(incomeFragment);

bottomNavigationView.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colorin);
                    return true;

                case R.id.expense:
                    setFragment(expenseFragment);

bottomNavigationView.setItemBackgroundResource(R.color.colorex);
                    return true;

                default:
                    return false;

            }
        }
    });


}
public void InitViews(){
    Toolbar toolbar=findViewById(R.id.my_toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle("Expense Manager");
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    bottomNavigationView=findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigationbar);
    frameLayout=findViewById(R.id.main_frame);
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle=new ActionBarDrawerToggle(






    this,drawerLayout,toolbar,
R.string.navigation_drawer_open,R.string.navigation_d 
 rawer_close
);

    drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
    NavigationView navigationView=findViewById(R.id.naView);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    dashBoardFragment=new DashBoardFragment();
    incomeFragment=new IncomeFragment();
    expenseFragment=new ExpenseFragment();
    presenter=new 
   HomeActivityPresenter(HomeActivity.this,HomeActivity.this);
   presenter.setFragment1(dashBoardFragment);
    //setFragment(dashBoardFragment);


}

public void setFragment(Fragment fragment) {

    FragmentTransaction 
 fragmentTransaction=fragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();


    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)){
        drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
    }else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }


}


   public void displaySelectedListener(int itemId){

    Fragment fragment=null;

    switch (itemId){
        case R.id.dashboard:
            fragment=new DashBoardFragment();
            break;

        case R.id.income:

            fragment=new IncomeFragment();

            break;

        case R.id.expense:
            fragment=new ExpenseFragment();
            break;

        case R.id.logout:
            mAuth.signOut();
            startActivity(new 
 Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class));
            break;

    }

    if (fragment!=null){

        FragmentTransaction 
 ft=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.main_frame,fragment);
        ft.commit();

    }

    DrawerLayout drawerLayout=findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

  }



@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    displaySelectedListener(item.getItemId());
    return true;
}


}
```

## HomeActivityPresenter

```
package georgiosApp.manager;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;

import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

 public class HomeActivityPresenter extends FragmentActivity implements 
 HomeActivityContract.Presenter {
 private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
 public Fragment fragment;
 public Context context;
 public FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
  Activity activity;

public HomeActivityPresenter( Activity activity,Context context) {
    //this.fragment = fragment;
    this.activity=activity;
    this.context=context;
    // this.mAuth=mAuth;
    //this.context=context;

}
public void setFragment1(Fragment fragment) {
    FragmentTransaction 
fragmentTransaction=fragment.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

}
```

## Error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: georgiosApp.manager, PID: 23647
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{georgiosApp.manager/georgiosApp.manager.HomeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2927)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager.beginTransaction()' on a null object reference at georgiosApp.manager.HomeActivityPresenter.setFragment1(HomeActivityPresenter.java:29)
    at georgiosApp.manager.HomeActivity.InitViews(HomeActivity.java:97)
    at georgiosApp.manager.HomeActivity.onCreate(HomeActivity.java:47)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6942)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1126)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2880)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:152) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410) 
 W/DynamiteModule: Local module descriptor class for 
com.google.firebase.auth not found.


enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

Change all `getFragmentManager()` to `getSupportFragmentManager()`.
If it didn't work change all `getSupportFragmentManager()` to `getFragmentManager()`

Comment: Thanks but that didnt solve my problem.It seems that maybe something is not initialised but i cant find it

Answer (score 0):

Setting the fragment should happen inside the activity and not in the presenter.
The presenter should not depend on the Android framework. By doing this you break the rules of MVP and also making the presenter untestable.

I would suggest to further read on MVP and have a look on various implementations like for example the one from google samples
[todo-mvp](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/tree/todo-mvp/)

Also there are numerous articles regarding MVP on Android that can help you.

[basics-of-mvp-the-android-way](https://hackernoon.com/basics-of-mvp-the-android-way-f75da407019d)

[model-view-presenter-android-guidelines](https://medium.com/@cervonefrancesco/model-view-presenter-android-guidelines-94970b430ddf)

[architectural-guidelines-to-follow-for-mvp-pattern-in-android](https://android.jlelse.eu/architectural-guidelines-to-follow-for-mvp-pattern-in-android-2374848a0157)